# Integer Wrapper Class Constructor: Unexpected Type

Tags: java, constructor

I have the following code:

```
public class BeanBag<Integer> extends ArrayList<Integer>
{   
    public BeanBag(int numBeans)
    {
        super(numBeans);

        Random fillBag = new Random();
        Integer convert = null;
        int rand;

        for(int counter = 0; counter < numBeans; counter++)
        {
            rand = fillBag.nextInt(2);
            convert = new Integer(rand);
            super.add(convert);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I compile this code, however, I get an error on the line `convert = new Integer (fillBag.nextInt(2));` with an error message that reads "unexpected type," yet the Java documentation for the Integer class's constructor says that I can pass in an int.  I'm not sure what's going wrong here and I'm learning Java.  All I'm looking for is a simple explanation of why this line is throwing an error, please.

Comment: Integer does indeed have a constructor taking int. the problem is not in the snippet shown

Comment: Post a complete minimal example, and the exact and complete error message. This error probably doesn't come from that code.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling the `Integer` constructor anyway. Just do `super.add(fillBag.nextInt(2));`. Or replace the whole snippet with `new Random().ints(10, 0, 2).forEach(super::add);`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. The given example code doesn't produce this error. ([example on Ideone](https://ideone.com/mghwVj))

Comment: @cppbeginner Integer class does have a constructor taking int.

Comment: @humblefoolish Actually, it does have such a constructor.

Comment: My guess is that you’ve written <Integer> somewhere.

Comment: @cppbeginner Or he might have defined a custom `Integer` class.

Comment: @shmosel I think everyone is in agreement here.

Comment: @Bucket I think so too.

Comment: I doubt anyone will ever read this, but the solution is to change the header to public class BeanBag extends ArrayList<Integer>. Since the type is always Integer, BeanBag shouldn’t be generic. With your version, “Integer” is a type parameter.